# How to set table as responsive for mobile and laptop and desktop in Tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

If there are only a few columns in the table, it will take up the whole screen on any device. But if there are a lot of columns, it might go off the screen.

What I want is for the table to always fit the screen, whether it has few or many columns. It shouldn't go off the screen. If there are many columns, I'd like to be able to scroll through them while keeping the first column in place, like in the picture for better understanding.

[image]

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js" defer=""></script>
</head>
<body class="bg-gray-100">
    <div class="flex w-full">
        <aside class="fixed relative hidden w-64 h-full min-h-screen bg-blue-600 border-t lg:block">
            <div class="px-6 py-1 bg-white">
                <div class="">
                    <p class="text-xl font-bold">Logo</p>
                                    </div>
            </div>
            <nav class="pt-3 space-y-4 text-base">
                <ul>
                    <li class="group hover:bg-primary-100">
                        <a href="dashboard.html" class="flex items-center px-6 py-3 text-white group-hover:bg-blue-700">
                            <svg width="24" height="24" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"
                                class="mr-3 group-hover:text-primary-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                    d="M3 12l2-2m0 0l7-7 7 7M5 10v10a1 1 0 001 1h3m10-11l2 2m-2-2v10a1 1 0 01-1 1h-3m-6 0a1 1 0 001-1v-4a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v4a1 1 0 001 1m-6 0h6">
                                </path>
                            </svg>Dashboard
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </aside>
        <div class="w-full">
            <div x-cloak x-data="{isSideMenuOpen:false}">
                <!--Mobile Nav-->
                <div x-show="isSideMenuOpen" x-transition:enter="transition ease-in-out duration-150"
                  x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100"
                  x-transition:leave="transition ease-in-out duration-150" x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
                  x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0"
                  class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-end bg-black bg-opacity-50 sm:items-center sm:justify-center"
                  style="display: none;"></div>
                <aside class="fixed inset-y-0 z-40 flex-shrink-0 space-y-6 overflow-y-auto bg-white w-72 xl:hidden"
                  x-show="isSideMenuOpen" x-transition:enter="transition ease-in-out duration-150"
                  x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform -translate-x-20" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100"
                  x-transition:leave="transition ease-in-out duration-150" x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
                  x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform -translate-x-20" @click.away="isSideMenuOpen=false"
                  @keydown.escape="isSideMenuOpen=false" style="display: none;">
                  <div class="mt-2 mb-4">
                    <p class="text-xl font-bold">Logo</p>

                                        <nav class="space-y-4 text-base">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="group hover:bg-blue-100">
                              <a href="dashboard.html" class="flex items-center px-6 py-3 text-gray-900">
                                <svg width="24" height="24" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"
                                  class="mr-3 text-blue-600 group-hover:text-blue-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                    d="M3 12l2-2m0 0l7-7 7 7M5 10v10a1 1 0 001 1h3m10-11l2 2m-2-2v10a1 1 0 01-1 1h-3m-6 0a1 1 0 001-1v-4a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v4a1 1 0 001 1m-6 0h6">
                                  </path>
                                </svg>Dashboardsdsdasaasas
                              </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                  </div>
                </aside>
                <div
                  class="w-full px-4 py-3 mx-auto bg-white border-b shadow lg:py-4 md:max-w-full lg:max-w-screen-full md:px-24 lg:px-8">
            
                  <!--Desktop Nav-->
                  <nav class="relative flex items-center justify-between">
                    <div class="flex items-center">
                      <div class="lg:hidden">
                       <p class="my-4">Logos</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden lg:block">
                      <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
                        <div class="relative px-2 text-gray-600" x-data="{ isOpen: false }">
                          <button @click="isOpen = !isOpen" @keydown.escape="isOpen = false"
                            class="flex items-center focus:outline-none">
                            <img src="https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/offers-homepage/us/en/homepage/twitter_adobe.png"
                              alt="avatar" class="w-8 h-8 rounded-full">
                            <span class="px-1 text-sm font-medium">Adobe Corporation</span>
                            <svg fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
                              <path d="M15.3 9.3a1 1 0 0 1 1.4 1.4l-4 4a1 1 0 0 1-1.4 0l-4-4a1 1 0 0 1 1.4-1.4l3.3 3.29 3.3-3.3z"
                                class="heroicon-ui"></path>
                            </svg>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex items-center gap-2 lg:hidden">
                      <button @click="isSideMenuOpen=true" aria-label="Open Menu" title="Open Menu"
                        class="p-2 -mr-1 transition duration-200 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                        <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                          stroke="currentColor">
                          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"></path>
                        </svg>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </nav>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div class="m-4">
                    <div class="relative">
                        <div class="w-full overflow-x-scroll">
                            <table class="divide-y divide-gray-200 table-auto">
                                <thead
                                    class="text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-left text-white uppercase bg-blue-600 whitespace-nowrap">
                                    <tr class="py-4 divide-x">
                                        <th scope="col" class="sticky left-0 z-10 p-4 bg-blue-600">
                                            Name</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                            Mobile Number</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                            Employee Id</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                            Email Id</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                            Address</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                            State</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                            Date of Birth</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                            Gender</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                            Aadhar Number</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                            PAN Number</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                            UAN Number</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                            ESI Number</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody
                                    class="text-sm bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="sticky left-0 w-full p-4 bg-white whitespace-nowrap">
                                            <div class="flex items-center gap-2 w-max">
                                                <img class="w-8 h-8 rounded-full"
                                                    src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/11.jpg"
                                                    alt="">
                                                <a href="" class="font-medium text-blue-600">John
                                                    Doe</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="p-4">9192939494</td>
                                        <td class="p-4">NA-1362</td>
                                        <td class="p-4">johndow@gmail.com</td>
                                        <td class="p-4">Raja Street, Pallipalayam, Tiruchengode</td>
                                        <td class="p-4">Tamilnadu</td>
                                        <td class="p-4">02-07-1995</td>
                                        <td class="p-4">Male</td>
                                        <td class="p-4">9876 5432 1098</td>
                                        <td class="p-4">XYZAB5678P</td>
                                        <td class="p-4">876543210987</td>
                                        <td class="p-4">ESI87654321</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </template>
                                    <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div
                        class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-4 pt-6 lg:flex-row lg:justify-between">
                        <div class="flex items-center">
                            <p class="pr-2 text-sm font-medium">Rows per page</p>
                            <select id="jobtype" name="jobtype" autocomplete="jobtype"
                                class="block w-16 p-1 mt-1 text-sm bg-white border border-gray-400 rounded shadow-sm disabled:cursor-not-allowed focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 sm:text-base">
                                <option>10</option>
                                <option>25</option>
                                <option>50</option>
                                <option>100</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <nav class="relative z-0 inline-flex -space-x-px shadow-sm"
                                aria-label="Pagination">
                                <a href="#"
                                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-l-md hover:bg-blue-100">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                    <!-- Heroicon name: chevron-left -->
                                    <svg class="w-5 h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                        viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                            d="M12.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414L9.414 10l3.293 3.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414l4-4a1 1 0 011.414 0z"
                                            clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#"
                                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                                    1
                                </a>
                                <a href="#"
                                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                                    2
                                </a>
                                <a href="#"
                                    class="relative items-center hidden px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 md:inline-flex hover:bg-blue-100">
                                    3
                                </a>
                                <a href="#"
                                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                                    4
                                </a>
                                <a href="#"
                                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                                    5
                                </a>
                                <a href="#"
                                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-r-md hover:bg-blue-100">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                    <!-- Heroicon name: chevron-right -->
                                    <svg class="w-5 h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                        viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                            d="M7.293 14.707a1 1 0 010-1.414L10.586 10 7.293 6.707a1 1 0 011.414-1.414l4 4a1 1 0 010 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0z"
                                            clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </a>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing `width: 100%` from the wrapper of the `<table>` that is the child of the `div.flex` and instead apply `flex-grow: 1; min-width: 0` via the `grow min-w-0` classes.

We apply:

- `flex-grow: 1` so that the element fills any horizontal free space.
- `min-width: 0` to override the implicit `min-width: min-content` caused by the horizontal flex layout. This means that the `<table>`'s `overflow-x-scroll` will not overflow, but instead, the `<table>` will overflow said element instead.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js"
      defer=""
    ></script>
  </head>

  <body class="bg-gray-100">
    <div class="flex w-full">
      <aside
        class="fixed relative hidden w-64 h-full min-h-screen bg-blue-600 border-t lg:block"
      >
        <div class="px-6 py-1 bg-white">
          <div class="">
            <p class="text-xl font-bold">Logo</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="pt-3 space-y-4 text-base">
          <ul>
            <li class="group hover:bg-primary-100">
              <a
                href="dashboard.html"
                class="flex items-center px-6 py-3 text-white group-hover:bg-blue-700"
              >
                <svg
                  width="24"
                  height="24"
                  fill="none"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  class="mr-3 group-hover:text-primary-900"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                    stroke-width="2"
                    d="M3 12l2-2m0 0l7-7 7 7M5 10v10a1 1 0 001 1h3m10-11l2 2m-2-2v10a1 1 0 01-1 1h-3m-6 0a1 1 0 001-1v-4a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v4a1 1 0 001 1m-6 0h6"
                  ></path></svg
                >Dashboard
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </aside>
      <div class="grow min-w-0">
        <div x-cloak x-data="{isSideMenuOpen:false}">
          <!--Mobile Nav-->
          <div
            x-show="isSideMenuOpen"
            x-transition:enter="transition ease-in-out duration-150"
            x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0"
            x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100"
            x-transition:leave="transition ease-in-out duration-150"
            x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
            x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0"
            class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-end bg-black bg-opacity-50 sm:items-center sm:justify-center"
            style="display: none"
          ></div>
          <aside
            class="fixed inset-y-0 z-40 flex-shrink-0 space-y-6 overflow-y-auto bg-white w-72 xl:hidden"
            x-show="isSideMenuOpen"
            x-transition:enter="transition ease-in-out duration-150"
            x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform -translate-x-20"
            x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100"
            x-transition:leave="transition ease-in-out duration-150"
            x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
            x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform -translate-x-20"
            @click.away="isSideMenuOpen=false"
            @keydown.escape="isSideMenuOpen=false"
            style="display: none"
          >
            <div class="mt-2 mb-4">
              <p class="text-xl font-bold">Logo</p>

              <nav class="space-y-4 text-base">
                <ul>
                  <li class="group hover:bg-blue-100">
                    <a
                      href="dashboard.html"
                      class="flex items-center px-6 py-3 text-gray-900"
                    >
                      <svg
                        width="24"
                        height="24"
                        fill="none"
                        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                        stroke="currentColor"
                        class="mr-3 text-blue-600 group-hover:text-blue-900"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      >
                        <path
                          stroke-linecap="round"
                          stroke-linejoin="round"
                          stroke-width="2"
                          d="M3 12l2-2m0 0l7-7 7 7M5 10v10a1 1 0 001 1h3m10-11l2 2m-2-2v10a1 1 0 01-1 1h-3m-6 0a1 1 0 001-1v-4a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v4a1 1 0 001 1m-6 0h6"
                        ></path></svg
                      >Dashboardsdsdasaasas
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </aside>
          <div
            class="w-full px-4 py-3 mx-auto bg-white border-b shadow lg:py-4 md:max-w-full lg:max-w-screen-full md:px-24 lg:px-8"
          >
            <!--Desktop Nav-->
            <nav class="relative flex items-center justify-between">
              <div class="flex items-center">
                <div class="lg:hidden">
                  <p class="my-4">Logos</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="hidden lg:block">
                <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
                  <div
                    class="relative px-2 text-gray-600"
                    x-data="{ isOpen: false }"
                  >
                    <button
                      @click="isOpen = !isOpen"
                      @keydown.escape="isOpen = false"
                      class="flex items-center focus:outline-none"
                    >
                      <img
                        src="https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/offers-homepage/us/en/homepage/twitter_adobe.png"
                        alt="avatar"
                        class="w-8 h-8 rounded-full"
                      />
                      <span class="px-1 text-sm font-medium"
                        >Adobe Corporation</span
                      >
                      <svg
                        fill="currentColor"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                        width="24"
                        height="24"
                      >
                        <path
                          d="M15.3 9.3a1 1 0 0 1 1.4 1.4l-4 4a1 1 0 0 1-1.4 0l-4-4a1 1 0 0 1 1.4-1.4l3.3 3.29 3.3-3.3z"
                          class="heroicon-ui"
                        ></path>
                      </svg>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex items-center gap-2 lg:hidden">
                <button
                  @click="isSideMenuOpen=true"
                  aria-label="Open Menu"
                  title="Open Menu"
                  class="p-2 -mr-1 transition duration-200 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                >
                  <svg
                    class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-800"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                  >
                    <path
                      stroke-linecap="round"
                      stroke-linejoin="round"
                      stroke-width="2"
                      d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                </button>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="m-4">
            <div class="relative">
              <div class="w-full overflow-x-scroll">
                <table class="divide-y divide-gray-200 table-auto">
                  <thead
                    class="text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-left text-white uppercase bg-blue-600 whitespace-nowrap"
                  >
                    <tr class="py-4 divide-x">
                      <th
                        scope="col"
                        class="sticky left-0 z-10 p-4 bg-blue-600"
                      >
                        Name
                      </th>
                      <th scope="col" class="p-4">Mobile Number</th>
                      <th scope="col" class="p-4">Employee Id</th>
                      <th scope="col" class="p-4">Email Id</th>
                      <th scope="col" class="p-4">Address</th>
                      <th scope="col" class="p-4">State</th>
                      <th scope="col" class="p-4">Date of Birth</th>
                      <th scope="col" class="p-4">Gender</th>
                      <th scope="col" class="p-4">Aadhar Number</th>
                      <th scope="col" class="p-4">PAN Number</th>
                      <th scope="col" class="p-4">UAN Number</th>
                      <th scope="col" class="p-4">ESI Number</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody
                    class="text-sm bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap"
                  >
                    <tr>
                      <td
                        class="sticky left-0 w-full p-4 bg-white whitespace-nowrap"
                      >
                        <div class="flex items-center gap-2 w-max">
                          <img
                            class="w-8 h-8 rounded-full"
                            src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/11.jpg"
                            alt=""
                          />
                          <a href="" class="font-medium text-blue-600"
                            >John Doe</a
                          >
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td class="p-4">9192939494</td>
                      <td class="p-4">NA-1362</td>
                      <td class="p-4">johndow@gmail.com</td>
                      <td class="p-4">
                        Raja Street, Pallipalayam, Tiruchengode
                      </td>
                      <td class="p-4">Tamilnadu</td>
                      <td class="p-4">02-07-1995</td>
                      <td class="p-4">Male</td>
                      <td class="p-4">9876 5432 1098</td>
                      <td class="p-4">XYZAB5678P</td>
                      <td class="p-4">876543210987</td>
                      <td class="p-4">ESI87654321</td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div
              class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-4 pt-6 lg:flex-row lg:justify-between"
            >
              <div class="flex items-center">
                <p class="pr-2 text-sm font-medium">Rows per page</p>
                <select
                  id="jobtype"
                  name="jobtype"
                  autocomplete="jobtype"
                  class="block w-16 p-1 mt-1 text-sm bg-white border border-gray-400 rounded shadow-sm disabled:cursor-not-allowed focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 sm:text-base"
                >
                  <option>10</option>
                  <option>25</option>
                  <option>50</option>
                  <option>100</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div>
                <nav
                  class="relative z-0 inline-flex -space-x-px shadow-sm"
                  aria-label="Pagination"
                >
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-l-md hover:bg-blue-100"
                  >
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    <!-- Heroicon name: chevron-left -->
                    <svg
                      class="w-5 h-5"
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                      fill="currentColor"
                      aria-hidden="true"
                    >
                      <path
                        fill-rule="evenodd"
                        d="M12.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414L9.414 10l3.293 3.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414l4-4a1 1 0 011.414 0z"
                        clip-rule="evenodd"
                      ></path>
                    </svg>
                  </a>
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100"
                  >
                    1
                  </a>
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100"
                  >
                    2
                  </a>
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    class="relative items-center hidden px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 md:inline-flex hover:bg-blue-100"
                  >
                    3
                  </a>
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100"
                  >
                    4
                  </a>
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100"
                  >
                    5
                  </a>
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-r-md hover:bg-blue-100"
                  >
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    <!-- Heroicon name: chevron-right -->
                    <svg
                      class="w-5 h-5"
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                      fill="currentColor"
                      aria-hidden="true"
                    >
                      <path
                        fill-rule="evenodd"
                        d="M7.293 14.707a1 1 0 010-1.414L10.586 10 7.293 6.707a1 1 0 011.414-1.414l4 4a1 1 0 010 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0z"
                        clip-rule="evenodd"
                      ></path>
                    </svg>
                  </a>
                </nav>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```